# Does `remember` only work with `MutableState` variables?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I was just doing some testing for one of my Composables when I found this very bizarre behaviour.

This code:-

```
{ //Composable-Scope
 var fired = remember { false }
 if(!fired) { Fire(); fired = true }
}
```

calls the methof `Fire()` on every recomposition.

On the other hand, however,

```
{ //Composable Scope
 var fired by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
 if(!fired) { Fire(); fired = true }
}
```

calls `Fire()` only upon the first Composition.

If this is the intended behaviour, is there a good explanation for why `remember` is not made universal? If it is not the intended behavior, I'll probably just file a bug.

Comment: Seems like only states are remembered. Can't find any good explanation. Kindly add the link to the bug here, in case you raise one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is intended behaviour.

During the first composition value of `remember` lambda is calculated and cached. On each next recomposition calling `remember { ... }` will return the cached value.

In your first code block you're creating a variable, which will get the same initial value on each recomposition. You can modify it during the composition code, but on recomposition it'll be reset, as if you were not using `remember` at all.

With mutable state remember does the same thing: it remembers the content of the lambda. But in this case the result is a wrapper class instance. This instance is the same between recompositions, but you can modify the value property of this object, that's why it lives thought recompositions.

Comment: Wait why is the wrapper class instance same between recompositions?

Comment: @MARSK because it's cached by `remember`. If you don't specify a different key, and the configuration isn't changed, (which may trigger remember values reset), your `remember` lambda won't be re-called, so the object will be the same. You can see it by removing the delegation(`by`) and adding logs to see the variable address.

Comment: Ok so why is the block 1 var not cached?

Comment: I specified no key, and neither a configuration change occurred

Comment: @MARSK it's cached. The cached value is `false`. When you're modifying the variable later, it has nothing to do with `remember`, so `remember` can't know it was modified.

Comment: Oh. How stupid. Can I delete this question so I do not appear dumb, please?